# Can't update Local Database using WPF Datagrid & DataAdapter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ado.net

I'm trying to reflect the changes being made in the DataGrid to my local database (SQL Server Compact Edition, in this case) but it fails. Here is the code:

```
        SqlCeConnection conn;
        SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter;

        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = DataModel.sdf");
            dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select * from Members", conn);
            SqlCeCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataTable.RowChanged += dataTable_RowChanged;
            dataTable.RowDeleted += dataTable_RowDeleted;
            membersDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    void dataTable_RowDeleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        dataAdapter.Update(sender as DataTable);
    }

    void dataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        dataAdapter.Update(sender as DataTable);

    }
```

membersDataGrid is the name of the DataGrid view in the UI. Have I done anything wrong? 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: you're passing the sender as parameter to dataAdapter.Update()

Comment: @jstreet I've checked the sender. It's the table with the latest modification. the one which should be stored in the database as the new table.

Comment: normally you would use the event parameter DataRowChangeEventArgs.Row for that purpose.

Comment: @jstreet I've tried that, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: wow... in reality it does work... i reproduced your code but just using regular SQL Server (not CE) and it did work, although that's not how i would do it. Try executing your code outside Visual Studio, otherwise your database may get over-written in your compile/execute cycle and you will never be able to see your changes. I'll post the code that worked for me, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Also, please note I'm using a strongly typed dataset that visual studio creates for you when you add a datasource from an existing database, just a personal preference. Another point : note i am using a local adapter within table_RowChanged event handler, as your code is using a class instance variable. In this case, the local adapter is more recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me. It is similar to yours, except that uses my localDB database (not CE). Also, make sure to test your code outside VS, otherwise the database file may get over-written in your compile/execute cycle and you will never be able to see your changes reflected in the database.

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WpfApplication14.Properties.Settings.NorthwindConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    CustomersTableAdapter adapter = new CustomersTableAdapter();
    NorthwindDataSet.CustomersDataTable table = new NorthwindDataSet.CustomersDataTable();

    adapter.Fill(table);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

    table.RowChanged += table_RowChanged;
}

void table_RowChanged(object sender, System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    using (CustomersTableAdapter adapter = new CustomersTableAdapter())
    {
        adapter.Update(sender as NorthwindDataSet.CustomersDataTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you dedicated to find the problem. Yesterday I realized the problem was in the primary key of the table. The primary key column must always reside in the DataTable, otherwise DataAdapter will lose rows track.